# Parallelising dataset on Tensorflow:throws error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have written the following function to define a CNN-model :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv1D, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import time
import tensorflow.keras.metrics

from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

    def convolutional_neural_network(x, y):
        print("Hyper-parameter values:\n")
        print('Momentum Rate =',0.25,'\n')
        print('learning rate =',0.05,'\n')
        print('Number of neurons =',30,'\n')
    
        startTime = time.clock()
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Conv1D(filters=64,input_shape=train_X.shape[1:],activation='relu',kernel_size = 3))
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(neurons,activation='relu')) # first hidden layer
        model.add(Dense(neurons, activation='relu')) # second hidden layer
        model.add(Dense(neurons, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(neurons, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
        sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.05, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.25, nesterov=True)
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy',tensorflow.keras.metrics.Precision()])
        history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, validation_split=0.2, epochs=10, batch_size=100)
        endTime = time.clock()
        print("Time = ", endTime-startTime)
        print("\nTraining Data Statistics:\n")
        print("CNN Model with Relu Hidden Units and Cross-Entropy Error Function:")
        print_statistics(model, x, y)
```

Now,I am trying to make sure that the dataset is parallelised to train the model simultaneously by using the code below :

```
def make_parallel(fn, num_gpus, num_outputs, **kwargs):
    in_splits = {}
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        in_splits[k] = tf.split(v, num_gpus)

    out_splits = [[]]*num_outputs
    for i in range(num_gpus):
        with tf.device(tf.DeviceSpec(device_type="GPU", device_index=i)):
            with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=i > 0):
                out_ = fn(**{k : v[i] for k, v in in_splits.items()})
                for j in range(num_outputs):
                        out_splits[j].append(out_[j])

    # tf.stack may be needed instead of tf.concat depending on the shape of some of your variables.
    return [tf.concat(x, axis=0) for x in out_splits]

# Finding how many devices are available
gpus = [x.name for x in device_lib.list_local_devices() if x.device_type == 'GPU']
num_gpus = len(gpus)

if num_gpus > 0:
    y_pred, y_pred_cls, cost = make_parallel(convolutional_neural_network, num_gpus, 3, x, y)
else:
    # CPU-only version
    y_pred, y_pred_cls, cost, f_vector = convolutional_neural_network(x, y)
```

The code is running fine,but throwing me following error :

```
y_pred, y_pred_cls, cost = make_parallel(convolutional_neural_network, num_gpus, 3, x, y)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: Why not use tensorflow's builtin way of training over multiple gpus? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/MirroredStrategy

Comment: I was trying that,but it threw me error.Maybe I can share that in another question ?